# How to format variable length values in a given column to same length output

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, spaces

From a requirements doc I need to pull data from SQL Server into a text file in what amounts to a [hl7](/questions/tagged/hl7) like format wherein the first column needs to fill positions 1-9, the next 10-27, the next 28-43 and so on regardless of the actual length of data in the column.

Given that each row / column combo will have different length of data, not sure how to approach this. Any ideas would be appreciated.

I've tried right space, left space etc. but they all just add spaces to whatever the actual data length is rather than filling out the length of the returned data to x length long.

```
SELECT 
CAST(LEFT(FIRSTNAME + SPACE(60), 60) AS CHAR(60)) 'LEFT'
FROM MLA
```

Something like

```
Robert      Gaskin          Portland
```

Comment: Your query from the question should work `LEFT(FIRSTNAME + SPACE(60), 60)`. This will make the column text 60 characters long regardless of its original length.

Comment: SELECT 
Len(LEFT(PHONENUMBER + SPACE(60), 60))  'LEFT'
FROM MLA results in length of 10 characters. Unless I'm missing something...

Comment: `LEN` function in SQL Server returns the length of the text **ignoring the trailing spaces**. That's why you don't see that `LEN` returns 60. But, the spaces are there. You can use `DATA_LENGTH` to verify the final result. Or just run the query and see the results.

Comment: Yeah, figured that out after commenting, my bad, my apologizes.

Comment: Now you can answer your question yourself.

Answer (score 0):

```
select RPAD( firstname, 10, ' ' ) as padded_name from MLA
```

Comment: This is oracle syntax. But the question (at least now) is tagged with sql-server

Comment: yes - i see... i will leave it for the Oracle users - hopefully no downvotes for that change...